# i am trying to fetch the data from mysql in pyqt5 and display it in a table widget

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5

here is the whole code. The problem I am having is i cannot get the data from lineTextEdit box to the %s wild card character in the mysql query. it works fine if i hard code the query and give a value from the database but the python stops and closes itself when i try to give the %s in query.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host = "localhost",
  username = "sameer",
  password = "Pr@tik123",
  database = "myschool")

class Ui_Search(object):
  def Submit_btn(self):
    firstname = self.fname.text()
    frstname = firstname.replace(" ", "")
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

for example in first line of code below if i write fname = 'germany' it works totally fine and i get the result in the tablewidget as i intended to but it fails if i give the following %s wild card character .

```
    query = ("select * from students where fname = %s")
    mycursor.execute(query,(frstname))
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    #self.table.setRowCount(0)
    for row_num, rowdata in enumerate(data):
      #self.table.insertRow(row_num)
      for col_num, coldata in enumerate(rowdata):
        self.table.setItem(row_num,col_num,QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(coldata)))
    mycursor.close()
  def setupUi(self, Search):
    Search.setObjectName("Search")
    Search.resize(828, 620)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Search)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 91, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(14)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 71, 31))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 70, 71, 31))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 70, 71, 31))
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.fname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.fname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 151, 22))
    self.fname.setObjectName("fname")
    self.lname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 100, 151, 22))
    self.lname.setObjectName("lname")
    self.dob = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.dob.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 100, 161, 22))
    self.dob.setObjectName("dob")
    self.Submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.Submit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 93, 28))
    self.Submit.setObjectName("Submit")
    self.Submit.clicked.connect(self.Submit_btn)
    
    self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.table.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 791, 421))
    self.table.setRowCount(4)
    self.table.setColumnCount(6)
    self.table.setObjectName("table")
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setItem(0, 0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setItem(0, 1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setItem(0, 2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setItem(0, 3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setItem(0, 4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.table.setItem(0, 5, item)
    Search.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Search)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    Search.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(Search)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Search)

def retranslateUi(self, Search):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Search.setWindowTitle(_translate("Search", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Search", "Search"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Search", "First Name"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Search", "Last Name"))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Search", "Date of Birth"))
    self.Submit.setText(_translate("Search", "Submit"))
    __sortingEnabled = self.table.isSortingEnabled()
    self.table.setSortingEnabled(False)
    
    self.table.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Search = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_Search()
ui.setupUi(Search)
Search.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sorry, if this is stupid and the whole bulk of code but i am desperately wanting to solve this problem. It displays no error msg but the python closes itself

Comment: Welcome to SO! Always include error messages/traceback in your questions.

Comment: python stops working and closes